# Sharepoint issue, selective behavior?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, sharepoint

Repost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840502/sharepoint-issue-selective-behavior

I was recently assigned a task in Sharepoint as part of my internship, and it's been puzzling me for some days. Note that this is the first time I'm using Sharepoint so I might be using wrong terms here.

They have a site that contains 2 web parts; a list called "Company Directory" and below it, a list (I think) called My Information. The way this is supposed to behave is that all users in the group "Employee Audience" can view both web parts.

Employees are supposed to "add a new item" to the Company Directory list where they will enter their personal information. After adding it, the bottom web part "My Information" should show the information they entered and an option to edit. So far, they got all of this working already.

However, there's an issue with certain employees where they can't see the information they have entered. I have tested different things with 2 employees, which belong to the Employee Audience group and can see both lists, but only one of them can see the information he entered and edit it.

I don't understand why it would work for one of them but not the other, I have tried making them add the information on the same date as well as on different dates, making them add the information from the same computer, but the same thing happened.

I'm at a loss now. Remember, I'm a newbie with this application so I'm probably missing something obvious, so whatever you can think of will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the exact case of their network ID to that which was entered in the list in SharePoint.  SharePoint uses CAML queries to lookup data in lists and CAML is case-sensitive.  If these are custom developed web parts, then the developer should probably look closely at the portion of his logic that queries the list for the current user.